# Output is not showing, spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Output is showing the schema, but output of sql query is not visible. I dont understand where I am doing wrong.

```scala
object ex_1 {

  def parseLine(line:String): (String, String, Int, Int) = {
      val fields = line.split(" ")
      val project_code = fields(0)
      val project_title = fields(1)
      val page_hits = fields(2).toInt
      val page_size = fields(3).toInt

     (project_code, project_title, page_hits, page_size)
  }
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
      val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]",  "Weblogs")

      val lines = sc.textFile("F:/Downloads_F/pagecounts.out")
      val parsedLines = lines.map(parseLine)
      println("hello")

      val spark = SparkSession
        .builder
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate

      import spark.implicits._
      val RDD1 = parsedLines.toDF("project","page","pagehits","pagesize")
      RDD1.printSchema()
      RDD1.createOrReplaceTempView("logs")
      val min1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE pagesize >= 4733")
      val results = min1.collect()
      results.foreach(println)
      println("bye")
      spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you running this code? Are you using a notebook? Something else? Please provide more information by editing your Question. Showing anything you do currently see as an output would be helpful.

Comment: I am running it in intellij idea

Comment: I noticed one thing, when i run it to print schema its printing normally, but when I add sql command and collect() method , program is finishing with exit code 1

Comment: Is it possible that `results` is an empty list? Try printing the size of results: `println(results.length)`.

Comment: You can also trying printing via the `show` method on Dataset: `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE pagesize >= 4733").show(false)`.

Comment: What is the use of  .show(false) . IT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed in the comments, using the [`show`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L778-L787) method displays the result of `spark.sql(..)`.

Since `spark.sql` returns a `DataFrame`, calling `show` is the ideal way to display the data. Where you where calling `collect`, previously, [is not advised](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3112-L3113):

> Running collect requires moving all the data into the application's driver process, and doing so on a very large dataset can crash the driver process with OutOfMemoryError.

```scala
..
..
val min1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE pagesize >= 4733")

// where `false` prevents the output from being truncated.
min1.show(false)

println("bye")
spark.stop()
```

---

Even if your DataFrame is empty you will still see a table output including the column names (i.e: the schema); whereas `.collect()` and `println` would print nothing in this scenario.